# Nivo Slider browser/tab/window blur/focus

Tags: jquery

JS newbie vs Nivo Slider.

Action that causes issue: User switches to a different tab or window

Problem: Nivo slider continues to run in the background. Upon returning to tab/window, my custom animations (added to `jquery.nivo.slider.js`) run out of control.

Example of my simple animation:

```
$('#element').animate({"top": "0px"}, "slow");
```

I actually figured out the solution and will post it for members to improve upon.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you stop the slider when going to another tab (via an onclick event, for example) and then continue running when you return to the inital tab?

```
$('#slider').data('nivoslider').stop(); //Stop the Slider
$('#slider').data('nivoslider').start(); //Start the Slider
```

Comment: The main problem I'm facing is finding a cross-browser friendly way to capture focus/blur events. The solution I found seems to work ok with newer browsers, although I haven't done extensive testing. Will the method you're suggesting stop the entire Nivo Slider loop? I'll give it a shot. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're doing on your page but these are native Nivo functions so they shouldn't be a problem. At first I thought you meant changing tabs within the site (that's why I said onclick event), but if you meant browser tabs, go with window.onblur/onfocus like you already discovered.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that worked for me. Please let me know if there's something I can do to make it better. Thanks!

```
if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) { // check for Internet Explorer

document.onfocusin = function() {
        vars.paused = false;
        //Restart the timer
        if(timer == '' && !settings.manualAdvance){
            timer = setInterval(function(){ nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, false); }, settings.pauseTime);
        }
    }
document.onfocusout = function() {
            vars.paused = true;
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = '';
        }
} else {

window.onfocus = function(){
        vars.paused = false;
        //Restart the timer
        if(timer == '' && !settings.manualAdvance){
            timer = setInterval(function(){ nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, false); }, settings.pauseTime);
        }
    }

window.onblur = function(){
        vars.paused = true;
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = '';
    }
```

}